# GoogleSignIn not working with YouTube API (Swift)

Tags: swift, oauth, youtube-api, alamofire, google-signin

I'm making an iOS app where users can watch videos from my YouTube channel. I want my users to be able to like and dislike a video. I have a like button that I want to rate the YouTube video. Here's the function for the button that I got from [YouTube's Rate API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate)

```
func rateButtonTapped() {
    Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate", parameters: ["id":VIDEOID,"rating":"like","key":API_KEY], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
}
```

This requires authorization. So, I've followed the [Google's GoogleSignIn guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating) and implemented it into my app exactly as Google says to. From what I can tell, it's working. The user presses the `GIDSignInButton` and then the user signs into their google account and allows access. I currently have only appended one scope

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl")
```

which is required to rate a YouTube video. But, the String response that I get back from Alamofire is

```
SUCESS: Not Found
```

and the video is not rated. So, I went back on [YouTube's Rate API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) page and at the bottom I find:

> **Error type** notFound (404)
>
> **Error detail** videoNotFound
>
> **Description** The video that you are trying to rate cannot be found. Check the value of the request's id parameter to ensure that it is
> correct.

So I'm assume that my VIDEOID variable (called in the Alamofire request) just isn't right. So I used the id provided by YouTube on the [YouTube's Rate API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) page. Same response and no rating. Does anyone have any idea what is going on? I've been stumped.

*I'm using Swift*

Comment: Try to use `JSONEncoding.default` as an encoding.

Comment: @the4kman Nope. That didn’t work. Hmmmm...

Comment: @JacobCavin The video id should be the ID parameter in the URL when you view the video in a browser.

Comment: Also @JacobCavin, the method type of the request should be POST.

Answer (score 0):

Its the VideoID parameter that is the problem (check the 404 errors reasoning in the link).

I suspect that the variable is an optional and so the parameter reads something like "ID":optional(VIDEOID)] or however swift formats optionals when printed.

I always create a parameters property to create the dictionary and then check it (print) and pass as a parameter to the AlamofireRequest.

Comment: I checked. It's just printing the id, no optional() string.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these option to sort out exact reason of your problem.
Just use this link along with your **id as VIDEOID** and also use oauth2.0 to authorize your HttpRequest in [Googles ApiExplorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.rate?id=tUCa3JcFILI&rating=like&_h=8&)(click here).

Hope you will see that rating can be seen in the given video id.It prove that these lines are false.

> So I'm assume that my VIDEOID variable (called in the Alamofire request) just isn't right. So I used the id provided by YouTube on the YouTube's Rate API page. Same response and no rating.

Now when there is failure in Oauth2.0 request authorization .There is return of

> Not Found

Please update your code with oauth2.0 service request authorization[Reach out here for help in integarting Oauth](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application).
Also render the code so we can help you.